# Get AD/LDAP user information

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I'm building a Firebase webapp that will be used inside a corporate environment using windows desktops and AD/LDAP. The webapp is hosted in the cloud outside the corporate network. The webapp needs to visualise some of the AD/LDAP user information like username and first name. Can this information be extracted by Firebase?

For clarity I don't need the user to be authenticated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, yes you can export the users declared in a Firebase project with the CLI `authexport` command, as a CSV or JSON file. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#authexport

Comment: it is the other way around: my Firebase project would need to know the user that is accessing the webapp from within the coorporate network. I would like to do this programmatically

Comment: Can you give more info on your exact needs. Since you say that you "don't need the user to be authenticated", how would you know (in Firebase) which user is accessing the app?

Comment: Maybe I am totally wrong, but you may pass the username in the URL when you call a page of the app, and write this info to the database. Not ideal but if your users don't authenticate there are not many ways to do that.

Comment: That is the exact question: can I know in Firebase which AD/LDAP user is accessing the app? I understand the user is authenticated in Windows but I dont need an authentication mechaniscm in my webapp. Just which user is accessing it (username first name)

Comment: You have to find a way to transfer this info to your webapp, and then from your webapp write that to Firebase database.